# Extract info from this data structure?

Tags: rust, enums, docx

I'm using [crate docx_rs](https://docs.rs/docx-rs/0.4.7/docx_rs/) to extract text from an MS Word file.

I don't understand how this fits together and why the following `match` statement is not working as I'd hoped:

```
let docx =  &read_docx(&read_to_vec(&self.path_str)?)?;
let document = &docx.document;
// ... type docx_rs::documents::document::Document
for (i, document_child) in document.children.iter().enumerate(){
    // ... type &docx_rs::documents::document::DocumentChild
    if i > 100 {
        break
    };
    let variant = match document_child {
        Paragraph => {
            "para" 
        },
        Table => {
            "table" 
        },
        _ => "other"
    };
    info!("variant {variant}");
    // ... always "variant para"
}
```

This compiles, but I get a compiler message as follows:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src\docx_document.rs:65:7
   |
62 |                   Paragraph => {
   |                   --------- matches any value
...
65 |                   Table => {
   |                   ^^^^^ unreachable pattern
```

The variants of `enum` `DocumentChild` are [here](https://docs.rs/docx-rs/0.4.7/docx_rs/enum.DocumentChild.html). I'm not at all clear why some of these variants are wrapped in `Box`. I also don't understand why, in the above code, although `document_child` is of type `DocumentChild`, the variant `Paragraph` is said to "match any value". I thought the action of a `match` on an `enum` like this was to discriminate into branches for each of the possible variants.

I am in fact analysing a .docx file with lots of tables in it... but I can't find a way to access them.

Comment: It thinks `Paragraph` and `Table` are just variable bindings. You have to either qualify the variant names or import them into the namespace, i.e. `match ... { DocumentChild::Paragraph => ...` or `use DocumentChild::*; match ... { Paragraph => ...`

Comment: The issue is that since `Paragraph` isn't in scope, rust treats `Paragraph => {}` as a wildcard pattern that always matches — like `_ => {}`, but binding the value to a variable named `Paragraph`. If you import or qualify as `DocumentChild::Paragraph` then rust has something fallible to match against.

Comment: @isaactfa Thanks, this solved it. But in fact, for reasons well beyond my understanding, going `DocumentChild::Paragraph =>` gave an error, "error[E0532]: expected unit struct, unit variant or constant, found tuple variant `DocumentChild::Paragraph`". But the compiler's suggestion, to do `DocumentChild::Paragraph(_)`, conversely, *did* work.